# dojo with xstyle issue with css keyframes

Tags: css, dojo

I am using xstyle in a dojo project, when trying to add some animation to a div using CSS 3 like:

```
@keyframes loadingSpinner {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg)   }
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
```

xstyle output (after using using xstyle doj build plugin):

```
@keyframes loadingSpinner from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
}

@keyframes loadingSpinner to {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

which does not make the animation works:

I would like to know:

- How to fix this problem (maybe I should rewrite the css suing xstyle transition)?
- Can I ignore this code during build process?
- Any work around?

Related: https://github.com/kriszyp/xstyle/issues/51